# Specman e: How to pass a verbosity in a variable to a message() action?

Tags: specman, e

I need to set a message verbosity using a variable, e.g.:

```
    my_write(my_verb : message_verbosity) is {
        message(BUS, my_verb, vt.text_style(PURPLE, "txt txt txt")); 
        // other logic
    };
```

This code causes the next compilation error:

```
*** Error: The verbosity parameter must be a constant of type 'message_verbosity'.
```

But actually even when I've defined the verbosity as constant field:

```
const my_verb : message_verbosity;
my_write() is {
    message(BUS, my_verb, vt.text_style(PURPLE, "txt txt txt")); 
};
```

I've got the same compilation error.

How the message verbosity can be passed in a variable to the `message()` action?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the message verbosity concept.
Every message has a fixed verbosity. Then you control from the prompt, what the unit's verbosity is, which has the message.

The content of the message doesn't change. You want to control, if the unit (with the message) is talking more or less.

You control the unit's verbosity using the "set verbosity ... sys.path.to.unit.inst" command.